# Doubly stochastic matrix in Markov and distributions

Tags: matrices, markov-chains, markov-process, stochastic-matrices

The transition matrix $\bf P$ of a Markov chain be a doubly stochastic matrix that is all entries are non-negative and all row sums as well as all column sums are equal to $1$. How can I prove that the uniform distribution $\boldsymbol{\pi} = \frac1k {\bf 1}$ is a stationary distribution of $P$

Comment: Do you understand, what does it mean to be stationary distribution?

Comment: I wanted a proof that a double stochastic matrix P uniform distribution is the same as the stationary distribution.

Comment: You mean, you want to show that the only possibly stationary distribution of double stochastic matrix is uniform? I mean, it false

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant.  @BigCoconut

Comment: $$\begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0& 0. 5& 0.5 \\ 0 & 0& 0. 5& 0.5\end{pmatrix}$$ and $(0.5, 0.5, 0,0)$

Comment: Yes. I needed a more theoretical proof.

Comment: Okay, sorry, May be I didn't get you right, I dont know how to build theoretical counterexample(

Comment: By definition $\boldsymbol{\pi}^TP =\boldsymbol{\pi}^T$ and the sum of the components of $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is one.  This stationary probability distribution is unique *iff* $P$ is *irreducible* -- you'll want to look into Perron-Frobenius theory for this.